# In triangle with incircle prove that $\overline{CQ}$ is parallel to $\overline{AB}$

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

> We are given a triangle $ABC$ whose incircle touches side $AB$ at point $D$ and side $AC$ at point $E$.
>   Point $P$ lies on segment $AC$ such that segment $IP$ is parallel to the segment $DE$, where $I$ is center of incircle. Lines $DE$ and $BP$ intersect at point $Q$.
>
> Prove that $CQ$ is parallel to $AB$.

[image]

I tried angle chasing, then some ideas with new special points, lines etc, but it doesn't give any solution. I would like any advice, any help. No solution.

Comment: What's $I$ and line $IP$?

Comment: I forgot to write this. $I$ is center of incircle

Comment: Unfortunately this is geometrically impossible!!

Comment: Problem which I would like to solve is like that. Geogebra shows that it's possible and it is probably true.

Comment: Have you sketched this triangle, incircle, points, in Geogebra, jpatrick?  You might try uploading the image, after having saved it as png or jpeg.  This is the kind of question where images are welcomed!

Comment: @MostafaAyaz: what do you mean by *this is geometrically impossible* ? This problem can be easily solved through trilinear or barycentric coordinates, for instance.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio have you maybe an idea of synthetic solution, without analitycal methods?

Comment: @jpatrick: there is a simple proof by trilinear coordinates and I have just posted a solution through projective tricks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Let us introduce a couple of additional points: $F$, as the intersection between $BC$ and the incircle; $R$, as the antipode of $D$ in the incircle. $PRI$ and $PEI$ are congruent and it is not difficult to check that $Q,R,F$ are collinear. Can you show $AB\parallel PR\color{red}{\parallel} QC$ by invoking Pascal's (or Brianchon's) theorem?